# invalid type comparison with Booleans in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, type-conversion

Trying to clean Country (Ctry) column in pandas dataframe (origin) based on other row level data, or other dataframes with similar data. See links for example data frames.

It will eventually feed two new columns in the dataframe giving correctly formatted country and a data quality "score".

[Origin Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpzTh.png)
[Nafta, Countries, and States DataFrames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NF2gR.png)

The function works on values that are in the lookup tables, or blanks, but when I pass "bad" data in, it gives a invalid type comparison. Testing this separately returns a boolean and works:

```
Nafta.loc[Nafta[col] == a].empty .
```

Not sure why this doesn't work.  I've tested the values, and its Boolean to Boolan.  See custom function and lambda.

```
def CountryScore(a,b,c): 
    if pd.isnull(a):
        score = "blank"
        if pd.notnull(b):
            for col in States:
                if States.loc[States[col]== b].empty != True:
                    corfor = States.iloc[States.loc[States[col] == b].index[-1],2]
                    break
                else:
                    corfor = "Bad Data"
                    continue
        elif pd.notnull(c):
            if (len(str(c).strip()) <= 5) or (len(str(c).strip()) > 9):
                corfor = "USA"
            else:
                corfor = "CAN"
        else:
            corfor = "Bad Data"
    else:
        for col in Nafta:
            if Nafta.loc[Nafta[col] == a].empty != True:
                score = "good" 
                corfor = Nafta.iloc[Nafta.loc[Nafta[col] == a].index[-1],1]
                break
            else:
                score = "pending"
                continue
    if  "pending" == score:
        for col in Country:
            if Country.loc[Country[col]== a].empty != True:
                score = "good"
                corfor = Country.iloc[Country.loc[Country[col] == a].index[-1],2]
                break
            else:
                score = "bad"
                corfor = "Bad Data"
                continue
    return score, corfor

origin["Origin Ctry Score"] , origin["Origin Ctry Format"] = zip(*origin.apply(lambda x: CountryScore(x["Origin Ctry"], x["Origin State"], x["Origin Zip"]), axis = 1))
```

Assume dataframes are loaded already.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find my mistake.  In the last column of Country, i compare a integer to string.  Had nothing to do with  Boolean. Fixed with:

```
Country.loc[Country[col].astype(str)== a].empty != True
```

I will end up wrapping most in this type of transformation.